# Wet bar builder stubbed out pipes, need help identifying

Tags: plumbing, basement

I'm trying to figure out what pipes belong to what for a wet bar in the basement the builder already stubbed out. I'm confused on to what the 3 pipes are coming out of the 2nd pictures wall? I have labeled them 1, 2, 3. I assume pipe 3 is water, just not sure if that would hot or cold. I was thinking hot for a dishwasher - but hoping for cold for an ice maker. There is a half wall already with hot and cold, and the drain for a sink. What would pipes 1 and 2 be? Any help would be much appreciated[image]

Comment: Is the electric receptacle always on or is it controlled by a wall switch?

Comment: Good question - I do not know but will ask my friend whos basement this is. Does this matter?

Comment: Mostly I was just wondering what the purpose of having an underside receptacle at a wet bar. If it was controlled by a switch then one could put in a tankless point of use water heater and have it give cold water if the switch was off.  Probably no one ever does that so it is not relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Vent
2. Drain

- cleanout

3. Cold water (single pipe is *almost* always cold water, but of course it could be hot.)

Comment: So does this mean that the vent for this would be one of those under the counter vents with a one way valve that allows air in but prevents air or waste water from coming out? Wouldn't it be useful for a wet bar to have hot and cold water for washing dishes? Of course even with just cold water supply one could divide the cold water into two streams (two pipes each with its own shutoff valve). One stream would go directly to the cold side of a two valve faucet and the other stream would go through an electric point of use water (tankless) heater to the hot side of the faucet.

Comment: Modern dishwashers [& clothes washers] don't have a hot feed any more. Too much hot water wasted in the feed pipe to be economically viable.

Comment: @Tetsujin Modern clothes washers don't have a hot water feed? This is certainly news to me and Bosch (my clothes washer maker), I might add.

Comment: @GlenYates - this might be another 'by territory' thing. Mine are Bosch too. Japan switched to cold water washing in the 90's, the rest of the world wouldn't follow suit. The EU tried to persuade us all to wash cooler in the 2000's, when I bought my last clothes washer, but it had twin feeds. When that finally gave up the ghost last year all the new ones now have cold feed only. Same with my dishwasher, which is about 5 years old now.